# Header image in html won't stay put no matter what I change

Tags: html, css

I made this website with html the other day: https://ghiblimovs.herokuapp.com/
The thing is, that even though the header image is centered on my screen, when my friend opened the website in her computer, the image was way more to the left and top side of the website instead. I have tried changing things and I played around with media queries since that's what everyone keeps mentioning around the web but something isn’t working… I am new to html and css so any help would be very appreciated!

This is my html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Ghibli Studio | Movies</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'core/main.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
   <div class=" header">

   </div>
   <div class="wrap">
       <form action='/' method="POST">
           {% csrf_token %}
           <div class="search">


               <input type="text" name="search" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Type movie name">
               <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
               <button type="submit" class="searchButton">

                   <i class="fa fa-search" style="font-size:24px"></i>
               </button>

           </div>


       </form>
   </div>

   {% if movies %}
   {% for movie in movies %}
   <div>
       <ul class="result">
           <style>
               @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis:wght@300&display=swap');
           </style>
         
           <h4>{{movie.Title}}</h4>
           <h5 style= "color:lightslategray;">
               Release date: {{movie.Release_date}} <br>
               Director: {{movie.Director}}
               <br>Producer: {{movie.Producer}}
               <br>
               <br>{{movie.Description}}
           </h5>
         

       </ul>
       {% endfor %}

       {% endif %}
   </div>


</body>
</html>
```

This is my css:

```
body {
    background: #D4E6F1;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.header {
    background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/sco/thumb/c/ca/Studio_Ghibli_logo.svg/640px-Studio_Ghibli_logo.svg.png) no-repeat;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 640px;
    height: 307px;
    background-size: 70%;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 340px;
}

.search {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    display: flex;
}

.searchTerm {
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid #AEB6BF ;
    border-right: none;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 110px;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    outline: none;
    color: #AEB6BF ;
}

    .searchTerm:focus {
        color: #808B96;
    }

.searchButton {
    width: 40px;
    height: 36px;
    border: 2px solid #AEB6BF;
    background: #D4E6F1;
    text-align: center;
    color: #AEB6BF;
    margin-top: 110px;
    border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
}

/*Resize the wrap to see the search bar change!*/
.wrap {
    width: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
html {
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #666;
}



h4 {
    margin-bottom: 500px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
    background: url(https://cdna.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/017/168/420/large/emrullah-cita-ghibli-clouds.jpg?1554902207);
    background-position: center;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 63%;
    border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    left: 38%;
}
h5 {
    margin-top: -50px;
    background: #F2F4F4;
    width: 20%;
    height: 290px;
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    left: 38%;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing margin auto on both right and left should always center it

```
.header {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/sco/thumb/c/ca/Studio_Ghibli_logo.svg/640px-Studio_Ghibli_logo.svg.png) no-repeat;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 640px;
  height: 307px;
  background-size: 70%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

However the image is a bit off centered as in there's a bunch of white space so it will still be a bit to the left.